# How to scrape a table from a website and create a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, concatenation

I am following a web scraping exercise on a table with Python, I am successfully able to print the column of the given table, but I am not able to create a DataFrame with it. The suggested append method can't work because it does not work anymore with pandas. The CONCAT method should work, but I am not able to make it work, I don't know how to use the `[i].text`

would you help me out?

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


url = "https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries"
PATH = 'C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]").click() #copy 

countries = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ("//*[@id='__next']/div/div[3]/section[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]//tbody/tr/td[1]"))
for x in countries:
    print(x.text)
```

what the tutorial suggest is this, but the method "append" cannot work because it's deprecated:

```
for i in range(len(countries)):
    df_population = df_population.append({"Countries": countries[i].text)}
```

What I am trying is this, but it does not work :

```
df_population = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Countries"]) # does not work
df_population = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(**[countries[i].text]**, columns=['Countries']) for i in range(len(countries))], ignore_index=True) # does not work
```

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium to get the `driver.page_source` and pass that to `pd.read_html` to create the `pandas.DataFrame`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
import pandas as pd


# auto install the chrome driver or pass a path like you currently are doing
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

# run headless
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
# create the driver object
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
# go to the website
driver.get('https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries')
# get the first table on the page
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
# close the driver
driver.quit()


   Flag        Country  2023 (Live)  2022 Population Area (km²)  \
0   NaN          India   1427068453       1417173173       3.3M   
1   NaN          China   1425713463       1425887337       9.7M   
2   NaN  United States    339780047        338289857       9.4M   
3   NaN      Indonesia    277263198        275501339       1.9M   
4   NaN       Pakistan    239928531        235824862     881.9K   

  Land Area (km²)  Density (/km²) Growth Rate World %  Rank  
0              3M           481.0       0.81%  17.85%     1  
1            9.4M           151.0      -0.02%  17.81%     2  
2            9.1M            37.0        0.5%   4.25%     3  
3            1.9M           148.0       0.74%   3.47%     4  
4          770.9K           312.0       1.98%      3%     5
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the population data from the mentioned website without using Selenium and loading it in a data frame is as follows:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.float_format', str)

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries').text, 'html.parser')
population_list = json.loads(soup.select_one('script#__NEXT_DATA__').get_text())['props']['pageProps']['data']

df = pd.DataFrame(population_list)
print(df.head())
```

output:

```
   place     pop1980      pop2000      pop2010      pop2022      pop2023      pop2030      pop2050        country      area  landAreaKm cca2 cca3  netChange  growthRate  worldPercentage  density  densityMi  rank
0    356 696828385.0 1059633675.0 1240613620.0 1417173173.0 1428627663.0 1514994080.0 1670490596.0          India 3287590.0   2973190.0   IN  IND     0.4184      0.0081           0.1785 480.5033  1244.5036     1
1    156 982372466.0 1264099069.0 1348191368.0 1425887337.0 1425671352.0 1415605906.0 1312636325.0          China 9706961.0   9424702.9   CN  CHN    -0.0113     -0.0002           0.1781 151.2696   391.7884     2
2    840 223140018.0  282398554.0  311182845.0  338289857.0  339996563.0  352162301.0  375391963.0  United States 9372610.0   9147420.0   US  USA     0.0581       0.005           0.0425  37.1686    96.2666     3
3    360 148177096.0  214072421.0  244016173.0  275501339.0  277534122.0  292150100.0  317225213.0      Indonesia 1904569.0   1877519.0   ID  IDN     0.0727      0.0074           0.0347 147.8196   382.8528     4
4    586  80624057.0  154369924.0  194454498.0  235824862.0  240485658.0  274029836.0  367808468.0       Pakistan  881912.0    770880.0   PK  PAK     0.1495      0.0198             0.03 311.9625   807.9829     5
```